# Joomla website hacked, Index file replaced nothing else

Tags: security, joomla

We have a Joomla 1.5 site here : http://printversal.com

It got hacked last night. All codes are there. Just index file was replaced.
Replacing back old index file displays nothing.

Can anyone point out any directions to look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than just index.php was affected.  I'd look at restoring *all* files that you have in backup, and possibly rolling back a database backup if you have it - much of Joomla's behavior depends on database values that may have been attacked.

The usual rant about upgrading to 2.5 applies, but I know personally that it's not always quite that simple to do.

Comment: Can't upgrade to 2.5 since some of the components are not available for that. Also, no database values were changed and no other index files too.

Comment: I understand about the upgrade..we have 20+ sites in the same state.  But clearly, something other than just index.php was changed, otherwise restoring that file would restore the site.  Something else has changed, so unless you have a debugging tool to walk through the code execution, you'll need to replace all the files that might have been affected.

Comment: how should we know what was affected? By the way, a colleague said that users were deleted from the database when he came today morning.

Comment: So, the database WAS affected, so you can be sure that many Joomla site settings were also altered.  You're going to have to look at restoring the site and the database.  I'd suggest saving the hacked site as is and possibly compare the them in the hope of spotting what changes were made by the hacker.

Comment: You could try looking at the servers logs to see which files were accessed most recently and as Greg P said, take a backup of the hacked site and look for file size differences and/or extra files added and so on.

Comment: ok we will replace the site with backup. but then, how can we assure no future attacks are made? We made this for a client and future attacks may lead to loss in our business.

Comment: @GregP: you said "The usual rant about upgrading to 2.5 applies" however I would only really say this to 1.6 and 1.7 users.

Comment: Seriously look at an upgrade strategy, or compare the before/after sites to find how they hacked it and take steps to prevent it.

Comment: there are a few components that might help prevent future hacks such as AdminTools by Akeeba

Comment: @Lodder - I understand, I just get irritated by incessant rants about the obvious, so sometimes get testy on the topic.  i WISH I had the resources to magically upgrade all old versions and stop using mysql_* anywhere it occurs. :)

Comment: ok I will note both the points! Thanks a ton! Another issue. I tried accessing site to see server logs as @Lodder pointed but now, I can't even access cpanel. It's not loading.

Comment: @AkshatGoel Goel: in that case, contact your host and they will be able to reset your password. All the best with getting things sorted

Comment: @Lodder now this is getting more serious as well as funny! They are down too.:( Site took 8 months to develop and we are yet to receive payment. We had a demo scheduled for tomorrow morning. :(

Comment: jeez thats not good :S When I develop sites for clients I usually take a backup every day or 2 just to be on the safe side. Would recommend you do the same in future and be sure that security extensions are the first to be installed, just to be on the safe side ;) just out of curiosity, what host are you with?

Comment: Put your backup onto a laptop. Show it to the client. Explain the situation. Good luck.

Comment: @Lodder I don't know. Colleague handles these details. I am just responsible for the coding part. He informed me that hosting service is down. Never mind, we have the site running back now.